# Android Database Not Always Getting Deleted On Uninstall/Install

Tags: java, android, sqlite, installation, uninstallation

when i try to uninstall my android app and reinstall it again to get the new updated database, the database sometimes does not get updated, i don't know why. 
Database gets updated after trying a random number of attempts of install/uninstall,

Can someone help me with this problem.

What I tried is:
when uninstalling, first I force stop the application, then I cleared the data and then uninstalled.

here is the code that is executed in the MainActivity when the app starts.

```
   try {
        File dbFile = getDatabasePath("MyDatabase.db");
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Datbase does not exist");
            this.copy("MY.db",dbFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in Copying: "+e.toString());
        try {
             AppLogging(TAG, "Error in copying Database:" + e.toString());
         }
         catch(Exception l) { 
         }
    }
```

Copy method

```
        private void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException {
    try {
        File CheckDirectory;
        CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
        String parentPath = CheckDirectory.getParent();
        File filedir = new File(parentPath);

        if (!filedir.exists()) {
            if (!filedir.mkdirs()) {
                return;
            }
        }
        InputStream in = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        File newfile = new File(folder);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; 
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close(); 
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in Copy: "+e.toString());
        try {
            AppLogging(TAG, "ERROR In Copy Method (Database) " + e.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception l) {        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adb uninstall package_name

Comment: can you please explain

Comment: @degrigorash But we can't tell the user to uninstall through ADB